# how to use android studio to find java file in sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, netbeans, hotkeys

such as Activity.java and View.java, I can't use CMD+O to find these file.
I try like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFWzT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot posted in your question, click "Include non-project classes"

Comment: Cool, please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark. thanks